# How to set radio button checked by default in Weebly

Tags: html, css, radio-button, checked, weebly

how can I set radio button checked by default in Weebly using html and css?
I'am trying to do something like this:

```
.wsite-form-radio-container input {
checked: "checked";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what the options are in Weebly, but for the default check you could **use only HTML**.

```
<input type="radio" checked>Blue<br>
<input type="radio">Red
```

Notice that I added `checked` to the blue one. This makes it checked by default.

To style a checked radio button you could **use CSS**.

```
input:checked {
    ....
}
```

Comment: In weebly I just drag and drop checkbox to the place where I need it. Thats why I'am trying to do this with only css.

Comment: Is there any option to get into the HTML code? Otherwise I suppose they should have a panel where you can set it's properties, like the name, state etc.

Comment: If HTML is not an option, you could try jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Just add 'checked' to the input tag like this:

`<input type="radio" checked>`

Comment: But is it possible to do it inside CSS?

Comment: Inside CSS not, if you don't want to use the html solution you can do it with jquery. @DainisZhogots